# Abstracting a class with generics

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, generics, mvvm

I have been learning Generics and have some pretty good understanding of it. Basically it seems that generics are a placeholder for a certain type to be determined at run time. Generally the letter `T` designates a generic but it is not limited to just that letter/name.

So re-inventing the wheel I can have a can have a method that can convert any type of list to an array like so

```
public static T[] ConvertListToArray<T>(List<T> list) {
    int count = list.Count;
    T[] array = new T[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        array[i] = list[i];
    return array;
}
```

Now I am trying to put this to use inside a base class I want to use for all my viewmodels. Let's say I have an interface named `IModelViewModel` (a viewmodel for any EF model class)

```
public interface IModelViewModel<T>
{
    T Model { get; set; }

    bool IsNewRecord { get; set; }

    void ConvertModelToViewModel();

    void UpdateModelFromViewModel();

    void SaveToDb();

    void UpdateInDb();
}
```

My logic is, any viewmodel that is created to represent a direct poco from EF must have a `Model` property to hold the original EF Poco, a boolean indicating if it is a new record to be added, a convert to ViewModel method (which basically fills `this` viewmodel's properties via the model, an UpdateModelFromViewModel method that update's the model from the view-bounded viewmodel, a save method and an update method. The T in this case is meant to abstract the interface so that it can hold **any** poco I put into it.

Now here is the base class.

```
public class ModelViewModelBase<T> : DependencyObject, Interfaces.IModelViewModel<T>
{
    public T Model { get; set; }
    public bool IsNewRecord { get; set; }

    public ModelViewModelBase(T model)
    {
        if (model == null || model.id == 0)
        {

            this.IsNewRecord = true;
            Model = new T();
        }
        else
        {
            this.IsNewRecord = false;
        }
    }


    public void ConvertModelToViewModel()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void UpdateModelFromViewModel()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SaveToDb()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void UpdateInDb()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The idea is: every ModelViewModel child class must have an EF poco object as it's model property. When the class is constructed, the boolean `IsNewRecord` must be set according to the state of the EF Poco. The class itself is not working due to the fact that I am not using generics 100% correct. Is this even possible what I am doing? If not, what would be the best way to get this functionality?

Comment: When you say it's not working, in what way is it not working? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Well in the constructor of my base class mode.id is not available. I am assuming it's due to the fact that the compiler has no idea if the `T model` has a property named id due to the fact that it is a generic. Also, Model = new T() does not work either. I am confused on how to work generics into this situation. Why does the compiler complain about `new T()` if all it has to worry about is creating a new type of whatever I give it?

Comment: manojlds has answered both of those points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add contraints:

```
public class ModelViewModelBase<T> : DependencyObject, IModelViewModel<T> where T:Model, new()
```

(assuming `Model` is the base class for your models)

Comment: Ahhh got you. So in here we restrict the types to the base class used for my EF models. Since I am using database first approach, having my models derive from a base would be bad. Maybe I can make a partial class for each and have those derive instead.